# Using Python to run a sox command for converting wav files

Tags: python, wav, sox

I would like to process `.wav` files in Python. Particularly, I would like to perform following operation

```
sox input.wav -c 1 -r 16000 output.wav
```

in every `.wav` file in my folder. My code is below:

```py
#!/usr/bin/python
# encoding=utf8
# -*- encoding: utf -*-

import glob
import subprocess

segments= []
for filename in glob.glob('*.wav'):
        new_filename = "converted_" + filename
        subprocess.call("sox" + filename + "-c 1 -r 16000" + new_filename, shell=True)
```

However, it is not working as expected that it's not calling my command.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `"sox " + filename + " -c 1 -r 16000 " + new_filename`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you write

```
subprocess.call("sox" + filename + "-c 1 -r 16000" + new_filename, shell=True)
```

what's actually going to be executed for an exemplary `TEST.WAV` file looks like this:

```
soxTEST.WAV-c 1 -r 16000converted_TEST.WAV
```

So you're missing the spaces in between. A nice solution using Python's f-strings ([Formatted string literals](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings)) would be something like this:

```
subprocess.call(f"sox {filename} -c 1 -r 16000 {new_filename}", shell=True)
```

However, I'd recommend switching over to [`subprocess.run`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run) and disregarding the `shell=True` flag:

```
subprocess.run(["sox", filename, "-c 1", "-r 16000", new_filename])
```

More information also at the docs https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html

> **Note:** Read the [Security Considerations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#security-considerations) section before using `shell=True`.

Comment: yeah I am not sure why it's not working. It has worked on other files but not on .wav files. I used ```for filename in Path('AUDIO').rglob('*.wav'):``` instead. Thank you! Happy Thanksgiving!